# Splitting a dataframe into multiple outputs based on a column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Relatively new to Scala and Spark, hoping to get some insight.

I receive data in parquet form. This data comes from multiple sources, and is structured like so:

```
/dataroot/businessdate=20170829/sourcesystem=storea/datasample.parquet:

| SourceSystem | BusinessDate | OrderDate  | (other columns)|
| StoreA       | 2017-08-29   | 2018-02-03 | ...            |
...
```

This data is partitioned by BusinessDate, then SourceSystem. I need to repartition the data so that it is partitioned by OrderDate. The spark job I create will need to be able to be run on a specified business date, and cannot create duplicated data or delete data from other business dates when generating output.

My current solution stalls while iterating over the OrderDates in my input. This is what I have:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Placeholder").master("local[*]").getOrCreate
val businessdate = args(0)
val inputPath = dataroot+"\\businessdate="+businessdate

val inputData = spark.read.parquet(inputDF)
val distinctOrderDates = inputDF.select(inputDF("OrderDate")).distinct
for(od <- distinctdates){
    val outputPath = outputRoot+"orderdate="+od
    //There's more code here to verify existence of output data, but this works for local development
    unionDF = if(Files.exist(Paths.get(sampleOutput))) { 
        //If output data exists, program stalls here
        val outputData = spark.read.parquet(outputPath)
        val filteredOutput = outputData.filter(not($"BusinessDate"===businessdate))
        val filteredInput = inputData.filter($"OrderDate"=== lit(od))
        filteredOutput.union(filteredInput) //assigned to unionDF
    }else{
        inputData.filter($"OrderDate"=== lit(od))
    }
    // Process stalls here
    unionDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(tempRoot)
}
```

Files are then copied from the temp directory into the proper output directory.

I don't get any error messages or weird-looking INFO messages. When I run the process, the temp output directories are created but not populated (if output data does not exist already). Otherwise, according to the Spark UI, the location where the program stalls depends on whether there is existing output data or not

Additionally, if I add a line that prints `unionDF.count` before the write operation, the program stalls there instead of during the write operation. This tells me that the issue is with `unionDF` being evaluated, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

**This all works fine for data where there is only one OrderDate in the input data**.

Ideally I would love to run a simple `partitionBy("OrderDate")` on the input data, but that doesn't solve the problem of avoiding duplicate data or overwriting existing data. Is there a better approach to this problem that I'm missing, or a way to fix the solution I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by converting my `distinctOrderDates` into a List. Iterating over a dataframe the way I did causes issues, even though I extract the dataframe values within the for loop and operate on those. Code I added was:

```
val distinctDateList = distinctDates.collect.map(_(0)).toList
```

I used that list instead of the distinct dates dataframe for the rest of the program.